# Как еще можно назвать стихотворение Мандельштама "Silentium"?

Tags: поэзия, литературоведение

Стихотворение называется Silentium (Молчание), но при его анализе ему стараются подобрать еще одно название. "Она еще не родилась..."  О ком или о чем говорит поэт? Есть мнение, что это Любовь, ведь Афродита — богиня любви. А может быть, это Поэзия или конкретное стихотворение, еще не написанное автором.

Когда-то мне приходилось делать школьный анализ "Silentium", но сейчас я вспомнила о нем под настроение дня или даже минуты (17 июля 2020 года, 11:20), а уж оно совсем не о любви. Или всё-таки немного о любви тоже...

А как вы думаете, о чем это стихотворение? И как его еще можно назвать, да и нужно ли это делать?

Она еще не родилась,
Она и музыка и слово,
И потому всего живого
Ненарушаемая связь.

Спокойно дышат моря груди,
Но, как безумный, светел день,
И пены бледная сирень
В черно-лазоревом сосуде.

Да обретут мои уста
Первоначальную немоту,
Как кристаллическую ноту,
Что от рождения чиста!

Останься пеной, Афродита,
И, слово, в музыку вернись,
И, сердце, сердца устыдись,
С первоосновой жизни слито!

Comment: Sharon, а зачем после "дня" запятая?

Comment: @tum_: отлично, я тоже)

Comment: Кажется, понял. Потому что подразумевается сказуемое?

Answer (score 2):

```
 О ком или о чем говорит поэт?
```

Версий много (любовь, жизнь, мысль,  тишина, поэзия), споры идут до сих пор. Лирический герой говорит о той, кто "еще не родилась", но уже является музыкой и словом, нерушимо соединяя в себе все живое. Я поддерживаю мнение тех, кто считает, что "она" Мандельштама - это **гармония красоты**, объединяющая в себе как поэзию, так и музыку. Это апогей всего совершенного, что есть в мире. Упоминание о море связано с богиней красоты и любви Афродитой, которая родилась из морской пены, соединив в себе красоту природы и высоту чувств души - она и есть гармония. Лирический герой просит Афродиту остаться пеной, подразумевая, что богиня являет собой **слишком громкое совершенство**. Возможно, во втором четверостишье автор намекает на библейский сюжет создания мира: из моря появилась суша, и под светом, едва отделенным от тьмы, стали видны красивые оттенки среди общей черноты океана. Под днем, который "светел, как безумный", может подразумеваться какой-то момент озарения и вдохновения, испытанный автором. Последнее четверостишье вновь отсылает к библейской теме: устыженные друг другом сердца скорее всего намекают на стыд, испытанный Адамом и Евой, после того как они вкусили плод с Дерева Познания. Здесь Мандельштам призывает вернуться к первоначальной гармонии - "первооснове жизни".

Silentium -  "молчание".  Тютчевское название с восклицательным знаком придает форму повелительного наклонения,  правильнее перевести как "Молчи!". Тютчев призывает наслаждаться красотой внешнего мира природы и внутреннего мира души без лишних слов. Мандельштам вторит словам Тютчева, однако избегает прямого призыва. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что ***"молчание" или "тишина" - и есть гармония красоты, которая "еще не родилась", но вот-вот должна появиться в умах и сердцах людей, позволив им безмолвно, в "первоначальной немоте" наслаждаться окружающим жизнь великолепием естественных чувств и эмоций.***

Мы наблюдаем здесь циклические повторения ("и музыка и слово - и, слово, в музыку вернись", "и пены бледная сирень - останься пеной, Афродита"). Рифмовка – кольцевая: АВВА (опоясывающая). Кольцо – символ вечности. Рифма мужская, чередуется с женской: родилась – мужская, слово – женская.

По стихотворению «Silentium» видно, как тщательно поэт подбирал слова. Потому что, сколько бы ни говорил Поэт о молчании, ему никак не обойтись без Слова. Вчитавшись в стихотворение, обдумав его, мы понимаем, что **смысл жизни в том, чтобы жить в гармонии с собой и с миром. А для достижения гармонии нужна тишина, чтобы услышать, насладиться музыкой и словом («И, слово, в музыку вернись»). Отсюда и название «Silentium», то есть молчание.**

Здесь он  использует образы, которые затем вновь и вновь будут возникать в его творчестве, поэт не раз признавался, что именно в сюжетах мифов видит  желанную  гармонию, которую он постоянно ищет в окружающих его вещах. "Рождение Венеры" Боттичелли также натолкнуло Мандельштама на использование образа Афродиты.

Интересна его мысль о том, что изначально было не Слово, а Тишина: «да обретут мои уста первоначальную немоту». Она – ненарушаемая связь всего живого, именно из нее возникли и музыка, и слово. Таким образом Мандельштам считает тишину видом искусства, но высшим,
идеальным искусством, из которого родились все остальные. А ещё  мысль о том, что замысел всегда лучше и глубже его воплощения. Первоначальный замысел всегда кристально чист, но творец стремится выразить его. И этим он не только дает идеям жизнь, но и обедняет их, так как возможности слова, каким бы прекрасным оно ни было, ограничены и оно не может отразить всей глубины мысли.

Афродита была прекрасна, но пена, из которой она вышла, таила в себе больше красоты. Слова в песне дополняют музыку, объясняют то, что понять тяжелей. Но невыразимое ощущение от прослушивания музыки глубже и прекраснее, чем впечатление от текста. Лирический герой мечтает вернуться к этой первозданной тишине, слиться с первоосновой жизни.

```
        как его еще можно назвать, да и нужно ли это делать?
```

Ни в коем случае! Нарушится интрига, уйдёт синкретизм - основной его приём, ведь всё, что ни назови, будет включать в себя гармонию - красота, тишина, любовь, поэзия, музыка...

Comment: Людмила, очень вам признательна за ваше мнение и ваш ответ, так как тема представляется мне очень трудной для анализа. Я, к примеру, уже не уверена, что смогу это сделать, хотя и собиралась, но согласна с тем, что менять название не надо. Всё-таки это именно «молчание».

Answer (score 2):

**В поисках Смысла…**

Ответ-пародия

После двухдневного поиска Смысла стихотворения я поняла, что найти его я не могу и искать больше не буду. Едва мне казалось, что Он найден, как понимание рассыпалось, как карточный домик.

И тотчас же Смысл явился сам и объявил, что **Он состоит как раз в том, что его там нет.** Шутка очень понравилась Ему самому, но только не мне.

–  А почему тогда "бессмысленное" стихотворение такое красивое, звучит как музыка, если я слов не понимаю?

– Так оно зашифровано Поэтом, – удивился моей бестолковости Смысл. – **У него-то как раз Слово в Музыку вернулось**. Ну, это такой творческий этюд на заданную тему.

– Всё сказал? –  спросила я.

–  Ладно уж, – сжалился надо мной Смысл, – про Гармонию еще добавлю. Золотое сечение, соотношение пропорций помнишь? Большее относится к меньшему, как целое к большему. Число «фи»,  по имени  древнегреческого архитектора Фидия: 1,62 или  62% и 38%.

– Ну и что?

– Вот как раз гармония жизни, любви, поэзии заключена  в гармонии души. Большая часть – это неизведанное, таинственное, скрытое от других, а свет – это ее проявленная часть. Не раскрывайся до конца – человек без тайны становится неинтересен людям, да и себе самому тоже. Магнетизм души гаснет без правильной пропорции  явного и тайного.

– Хорошо, спасибо, я тебя поняла.

А что я, собственно,  поняла из всей этой истории? А вот это уже тайна…

**Эпилог**

Потом мне часто вспоминалось это стихотворение – отдельные строки или весь текст.  Каждый образ сам по себе казался очень красивым, волнующим, но никакого отдельного **Смысла** уже не имел.

Но разве не так же звучит **музыка?**  Она тоже выражает чувства с помощью звуков, но не слов, и это самое верное их выражение. Это те эмоции, когда  нет еще ничего, даже замысла стиха, но есть только **предчувствие,** предрождение.

Такие ощущения **самые истинные**, так как словом нельзя выразить всю полноту поэтической мысли – «мысль изреченная есть ложь» **по Тютчеву**. И в какой-то мере это похоже на предчувствие любви – «люблю ли тебя – я не знаю», как  у А.К. Толстого. Ничего еще нет – **только «пены  бледная сирень».**

Слово –  оно как  **безумие света** над темным и таинственным морем глубинных чувств. И у Мандельштама  его понимание **поэзии как молчания** выражено не прямым текстом, как У Тютчева, а **музыкой**, которая сложена из слов, но делима на слова по своей сути. Эта музыка рождает непосредственное чувство и позволяет пережить то ощущение, которое испытывает поэт еще до рождения стиха.

Наверное, это особый вид поэзии, когда стихотворение не делится на части,  а слова не выражают прямой **Смысл**, но имеют совсем другое значение.

А может быть, мы  вообще очень поверхностно понимаем поэзию, придавая большое значение только **Смыслу** сказанного, но при этом не чувствуем ее **многомерности и глубины**.

Comment: Браво! "Человек без тайны неинтересен людям". У Тютчева - другое, лично прочувствованное, диалог с самим собой:нужно молчать, чтобы защитить свое личное счастье. Вспомним знакомство  с Элеонорой Петерсон ,предложение. Когда он получил согласие, вопреки ожиданиям, не мог поверить своему счастью. Поэтому он и боится спугнуть лишним словом семейное счастье. Он как бы предчувствовал беду. Элеонора умерла после неудачного возвращения в Россию на пароходе, на котором возник пожар (кстати, на этом же пароходе был и И.С. Тургенев). Она после этого так и не смогла оправиться и умерла на руках Тютчева.

Comment: Людмила, но у меня же ответ-пародия, какой с него спрос. Шутка ― она и есть шутка.   Я правда не могу составить цельное (с моей точки зрения) суждение, какая-нибудь деталь обязательно не вписывается. Что касается Тютчева, то его стихотворение считают философским,  о личных мотивах мало кто знает, Возможно, поэт  записал личные впечатления, но потом осмыслил сказанное в общем плане (или другие осмыслили). Например (учебный материал): Посвящен стих теме, которая волновала многих поэтов – одиночеству творческого человека и необходимости оберегать свой внутренний мир, хранить его целостность.

Answer (score 0):

ОТВЕТЫ НА ТЕМЫ, КОТОРЫЕ БЫЛИ ОБОЗНАЧЕНЫ В КОММЕНТАРИЯХ

**1. Почему я не считаю подобные вопросы офтопиком на форуме русского языка?**

Язык изучает **форму речи** (лексику, морфологию, синтаксис), но  форма нам интересна не сама по себе, а как выражение определенного **содержания.** Особенно показателен в этом плане **синтаксис**.

Мы учимся соединять слова, составлять словосочетания, простые и сложные предложения. Но даже на этом этапе осваиваем только **азы, базовые понятия**. К примеру, практически не изучаем структуру предложения и прежде всего **порядок слов.**  Он выбирается интуитивно, но на таком уровне и остается, и это уже не есть хорошо. В разговорной речи мы эту проблему как-то решаем, а на письме начинаем ошибаться.

Далее мы переходим к следующей структуре – изучаем **текст**. Смотрим, как он делится  на абзацы,  как связаны между собой предложения. Также даем ему семантическую характеристику: повествование, описание, рассуждение. Но это тоже только основы, **не писательское мастерство.**

И все это касается повествовательной речи, а как же речь  **стихотворная**? Наверное, там тоже есть **особые композиционные приемы**, о которых мы вообще мало что слышали. Даже если мы сами не пишем стихи, то как нам тогда приобщиться к прекрасному, как понять, что хотел сказать поэт.

Поэтому так много **непонятых стихотворений** известных русских поэтов, которые использовали особую образность и более сложное построение стиха. Вот и **Мандельштама,** как я думаю, можно отнести к таким поэтам, а Silentium  – одно из известных его стихотворений, которое изучается в школе. Более того, там вам могут предложить написать сочинение на тему **«Тютчев и Мандельштам»**, где нужно сравнить два эти произведения с **одинаковым названием**.

У Тютчева в этом стихотворении приведено очень известное высказывание **«мысль изреченная есть ложь»**, значит, и Мандельштам должен был коснуться этой темы. Но тогда получается, что **тема Афродиты** не будет основной, а она в композиции занимает главное место. Вот вам и стихотворение о любви!

В старых архивах я нашла свое **сочинение «Тютчев и Мандельштам».** Так себе, ничего, есть немного оригинальности, но в основном анализировалась не форма, а содержание по образцу «как я это понимаю». А это тоже базовый уровень прочтения, при таком анализе **настоящего общения с поэтом не получится**. А вот более позднее сочинение, написанное для конкурса и с какими-то футуристическим замашками, к сожалению, потерялось.

**2. О важности запятых**

Наиболее распространённым знаком препинания в русском языке считается **запятая** (от глагола  пять в значении держать, останавливать), этот знак встречается **уже в XV веке.**

А вот мы в XXI веке **недооцениваем** важность запятых. Я не буду много распространяться на эту тему, но приведу недавний пример, где задавался вопрос именно **о знаках препинания в стихотворении**.

С единым знаком «точка и запятая» мы разобрались, но я предлагала поставить **еще всего лишь  одну запятую**  – чтобы слово «в сущности»  стало не обстоятельством, а обособленным вводным словом. Надо сказать, что поэт меня не понял и ставить запятую категорически отказался.

Я же видела, что этот прием переведет **простое утверждение** «предмет имеет признак» во **взаимообратное тождество**: предмет – это признак, а признак – это предмет. Такой вариант выглядел бы намного интереснее и значительнее, а смысл при этом не менялся бы.

Вот так **одна запятая меняет всю композицию стиха**.  Так, может быть, наши знания в области русского языка для поэтов всё-таки не лишние? Разве не нужна им помощь в определении грамматики и в постановке знаков препинания?