# Еще раз о Silentium Мандельштама

Tags: поэзия, литературоведение

Мельком просматривая анализы стихотворения в Сети, я обратила внимания на запись пользователя о том, что мало кто раскрывает **смысл двух последних строк**: «И, сердце, сердца устыдись, С первоосновой жизни слито».  Возможно, это действительно так, многие обходят концовку стороной.

Я тоже не стала рассматривать эти строки, **не до конца понимая их смысл**, но теперь думаю, что это надо бы сделать. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461457/Как-еще-можно-назвать-стихотворение-Мандельштама-silentium](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461457/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0-silentium)

К тому же я обратила внимание **на разную пунктуацию.** У меня есть сборник в серии «Великие поэты» (2011 год), там дается вариант стихотворения из сборника «Камень» **1910 года**,  где **обращение не выделено запятыми.** Может быть, это вообще не обращение? Но в большинстве редакций в Интернете эти запятые поставлены, хотя тоже не везде, также есть указание, что стихотворение редактировалось **в 1935 году.**

**И возникают такие вопросы:** В чем заключалась редактирование?  Когда, кем и почему обращение было выделено запятыми? Какое значение поэт вкладывает в слово «сердце»?

Встретилось мне **такое толкование**: «По-видимому, заключительные строки означают, что сердце – центр человека (каждого человека!),  и оно более всего отвечает за   дела и слова каждого. Глубиной своего сердца все люди слиты «с первоосновой жизни», что расширяет потенциальную семантику данного обращения как  обращенности к любому человеческому сердцу». http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_8_8

Не очень-то оно меня устроило, показалось искусственным.  Мне бы хотелось, чтобы эти слова гармонично вписались в единую трактовку стиха, а здесь понимание отдельного фрагмента.

Может быть, кто-нибудь поможет решить **хотя бы один** из этих вопросов?

Спасибо.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** ОТ 30.11.2020

А надо ли вообще определять **точный смысл каждого слова**? Есть мнение, что дословное восприятие искажает созданный поэтом образ, делит его на фрагменты, и это, безусловно, так.

Но иногда речь идет  даже **не о смысле** конкретного слова, а о его **месте** в  общей картине, о гармоничном сочетании отдельных слов.  Образ этого стихотворения представляется мне **нежно-мерцающим, написанным пастельными красками**, и яркое пятно может нарушить его.

И вот непонятый смысл –  это как раз и есть такая краска, которая «царапает» слух и кажется чуждой. Поэтому и хочется **«проверить»   слово и принять его как необходимое, а не случайное.** Тогда оно или сольется с общим фоном, не выделяясь на нем, или, напротив, сохранит свою яркую индивидуальность.

И все-таки хочется вернуться к заключительной фразе стихотворения.
**Что же хотел сказать нам юный поэт в  том далеком 1910 году**?

Мир еще не родился, не проявлены темные глубины его бытия. Мир – это единая структура, **где есть только любовь, и ничего, кроме любви**. Нет ничего  отдельно существующего: ни слова, ни музыки, ни живой материи – разных сердец. Вернуться туда, в предрождение, в молчание – вот что нужно художнику для  его творчества.

Осипу Мандельштаму было тогда 19 лет;  он жил во Франции, учился в Сорбонне, увлекался творчеством Ш. Бодлера, П. Верлена, Ф. Вийона.

Answer (score 1):

В гугло-книгах можно искать издания, ограничивая поиск периодом дат. [Вот первая половина XX в.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1138&bih=506&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1950&tbm=bks&ei=RnQiX_XaMeX4qwHk07W4Dg&q=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&oq=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&gs_l=psy-ab.3...626765.626765.0.629868.1.1.0.0.0.0.123.123.0j1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Dm4OnSItAw0) Стихотворение написано в 1910 г. В этом же году было первое издание, в котором последнее четверостишие выглядит так (здесь и далее — в современном написании):

Останься пеной, Афродита,
И слово в музыку вернись!
И сердце сердца устыдись,
С первоосновой жизни слито.

В издании 1913 г. оно выглядело чуть иначе:

Останься пеной, Афродита,
И слово в музыку вернись,
И сердце сердца устыдись,
С первоосновой жизни слито.

В изданиях 1923 и 1925 годов уже "современная" пунктуация. В послевоенных изданиях всё ограничивается этими тремя вариантами — вероятно, выбор варианта зависел только от выбора источника.

Моё понимание продолжает объяснение Людмилы (см. связанный вопрос). Здесь под словом "сердце" понимается и орган — основа жизни, с одной стороны, и, скажем так, душа, с другой. Душа является для органа такой же основой, как музыка для слова. Как и слово, "рождённое" сердце-орган теряет первозданную чистоту, о чём сожалеет автор.

Поэтому запятые нужны.

Comment: Спасибо за запятые,  безмерно Вам благодарна, просто в долгу перед Вами. Что касается толкования, то оно мне понятно: слово — музыка, сердце — душа. С другой стороны,   я не думаю, что первооснова жизни делится на части: душа, музыка и т.д. Эти категории более высокого уровня, но не первооснова, которая должна быть единой.

Comment: @Sharon В моём понимании первооснова жизни касается только сердца-души и, конечно, ни на что не расчленяется. Не думаю, что смогу выразить более точно своё понимание словами. Если честно, мне даже не очень хочется это делать — как будто из-за этого что-то портится.

Comment: Безусловно, да, портится, поэтому я как раз против поиска Смысла в каждом слове и в каждом образе, мне хочется воспринимать их как единое целое, а не по частям. Тем не менее хотелось бы расшифровать символ, слово как-то не очень вяжется с остальной поэтикой стиха, мне так вообще представляется немного неудачным. Слово "чувство" подошло бы сюда, но автор не стал его использовать.   Интересно, а сам Мандельштам или другие известные поэты из его круга что-нибудь говорили о стихотворении? Всё-таки мнение критиков и самих служителей муз - это разные вещи.